# Update multiple phone numbers in contact

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am tried to update multiple phone numbers of specific contact using following
code:

```
for(int j=0;j<allPhoneNumbersLength;j++)
{
PhoneInfo phoneInfo = (PhoneInfo) allPhoneNumbers.elementAt(j);
String phoneValue = phoneInfo.getValue();
int phoneType = phoneInfo.getIndex(); // phoneType = Phone.TYPE_HOME,  Phone.TYPE_WORK, etc
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builderPhone = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?"+" AND "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?" + " AND "+Phone.TYPE+"=?",  new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(phoneType)});
if(phoneType == Phone.TYPE_HOME)
{
builderPhone.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneValue)
.withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME);
}
else if(phoneType == Phone.TYPE_WORK)
{
builderPhone.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneValue)
.withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
}
else if(phoneType == Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME)
{
builderPhone.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneValue)
.withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME);
}
op_list.add(builderPhone.build());

}
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list);
```

Using this code I am trying to update three numbers, but only "TYPE_FAX_HOME"
number is updated and other two numbers are removed from contact.

Please help me.

Comment: Firstly, you're using **else-if** here. I hope you know that only 1 of the statements among the ladder will be entered.
Next, what is the value "**phoneType**" holding?

Answer (score 2):

I've learnt from your code that, you're using the **same** phone number value for all the 3 types. Hence, while displaying, android will display only **1** of them for the contact. But if you actually **edit** the contact, there you can see that, all the 3 types have been populated with the same number.

P.S: I'm assuming that the contact for which you're trying to do the edit, already has some number populated for all the 3 types. If not, please create them and then try running your code.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But same phone number populated with same type three times. Should you know why?

Comment: my friend, you have used **phoneValue** everywhere. I really doubt if that changes. Check your **FOR** loop. It has the same **phoneValue** for all the phone number types.

Comment: I have edited the code, phoneValue also changed as well phoneType.

Comment: if you get, different values for every "**String phoneValue = phoneInfo.getValue();**", then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Wow ... ! why you use the "if" statement ?!
 your code could be like this :

```
for(int j=0;j<allPhoneNumbersLength;j++)
{
    PhoneInfo phoneInfo = (PhoneInfo) allPhoneNumbers.elementAt(j);
    int phoneType = phoneInfo.getIndex(); // phoneType = Phone.TYPE_HOME,  Phone.TYPE_WORK, etc
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builderPhone = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?"+" AND "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?" + " AND "+Phone.TYPE+"=?",  new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(phoneType)});
    builderPhone.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneValue)
        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, phoneType);
    op_list.add(builderPhone.build());
}
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list);
```

Comment: Great catch.
I will change the code.
Should you know why last phone number updated, and why others numbers are removed from contact?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Android programmer but i think the problem is in last line of code , the loop update the contact info in each step but not apply it , at the end step of the loop apply update and the last changes should be apply , if you change your code like this i think it should work , it means for each loop's step the contact info will update :

```
for(int j=0;j<allPhoneNumbersLength;j++)
{
    PhoneInfo phoneInfo = (PhoneInfo) allPhoneNumbers.elementAt(j);
    int phoneType = phoneInfo.getIndex(); // phoneType = Phone.TYPE_HOME,  Phone.TYPE_WORK, etc
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builderPhone = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?"+" AND "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?" + " AND "+Phone.TYPE+"=?",  new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(phoneType)});
    builderPhone.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneValue)
        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, phoneType);
    op_list.add(builderPhone.build());
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Android Emulator. Code works fine in real device.
Thanks for all your help.