# PhoneInfo java class in Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-contacts, phone-number

Im trying to create android app for updating contact multiple phone numbers on Xamarin. I found code below but on java (I have changeв java to c# already)

```
public void MultipleNulbers(int allPhoneNumbersLength, string Id)
    {
        List<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new List<ContentProviderOperation>();
        for (int j = 0; j < allPhoneNumbersLength; j++)
        {
            PhoneInfo phoneInfo = (PhoneInfo)allPhoneNumbers.ElementAt(j);
            int phoneType = phoneInfo.GetIndex(); // phoneType = Phone.TYPE_HOME,  Phone.TYPE_WORK, etc
            ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
            builder.WithSelection(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId + "=?" + " AND " + 
                                  ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype + "=?" + " AND " +
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type + "=?", new String[] 
                                  { 
                                      Convert.ToString(Id), 
                                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentItemType, 
                                      Convert.ToString(phoneType) 
                                  });
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, redactTextNumber.Text);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type,
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.TypeCustom);
            ops.Add(builder.Build());
            this.ContentResolver.ApplyBatch(ContactsContract.Authority, ops);
        }
    }
```

But visual studio dont understand Phone info class. I would like to know, is there some methods for updating different phone numbers of 1 contact, or how can I replace PhoneInfo on Xamarin.

Comment: PhoneInfo doesn't appear to be a standard Android class.  Where did you get the original java sample from?  Where does allPhoneNumbers come from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785210/update-multiple-phone-numbers-in-contact

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785210/update-multiple-phone-numbers-in-contact

Comment: I guess i found question, but still i can't get phone nubers labels

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dictionary<string, int> RedactPhoneNumbers(string Id)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> numbersAndTypes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        List<string> allNumbers = new List<string>();
        List<int> allTypes = new List<int>();
        ContentResolver cr = ContentResolver;
        ICursor pCur = cr.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = ?", new String[] 
                                { 
                                    Id 
                                },
                                null);
        while (pCur.MoveToNext())
        {
            int phNumber = pCur.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number);
            allNumbers.Add(pCur.GetString(phNumber));
            ICursor lCur = cr.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, new String[] 
                                    { 
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type, 
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Label 
                                    },
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number + " = ?", new String[] 
                                    { 
                                        Convert.ToString(phNumber)
                                    },
                                    null);
            while (lCur.MoveToNext())
            {
                int lblIndex = lCur.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Label);
                allTypes.Add(lCur.GetInt(lblIndex));
            }
            lCur.Close();
        }
        pCur.Close();
        numbersAndTypes = allNumbers.ToDictionary(x => x, x => allTypes[allNumbers.IndexOf(x)]);
        return numbersAndTypes;
    }
```

Comment: Help me plz make right request to get labels. My method dont get any labels to dictionary